# Javascript not working on asp.net development server

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When i run my web project from asp.net development server, css and javascript stops working. in morning it was working fine. then suddenly it stopped working. i have cleared the cache but no success.

Comment: What did you change yesterday?

Comment: What does "stopped working" mean? It is a very poor description of the actual problem.

Comment: nothing.. it happens before. at that time i just changed the port and it started working. but this time i tried different ports but no success

Comment: yeah its poor description. actually i cannnot explain what actually is happenning. its kinda weired.

Answer (score 1):

It may be that you touched some client side code, for example even a little html may break your javascript code. You should download some tool that compares files with previous versions so you know exactly what is happening